# Can anyone convert this VB.NET code to VBScript?

Tags: vb.net, vbscript

Anybody out there that can help convert this small chunk of VB.NET to VBScript, I didn't realise when I was writing my tester app that the application I was going to use it in is all VBScript =(

The code gets a table from the database, then writes a couple of lines and then the table to a tab delimited file. I understand I may have to rewrite the part with Lambda completely? I may have to start again but if anyone can do this I would be appreciative!

```
Private dataTable As New DataTable()

Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
PullData()
End Sub

Public Sub PullData()
'Get data from DB into a DataTable
Using conn As New SqlConnection("Server=.\sqlexpress;Database=DB;User Id=User;Password=Password;")
    Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT areaID as 'Pond Number', storageDescription + SPACE(1) + areaID as 'Pond Name', " & vbCr & vbLf & "case when fishWeight = 0 then 0 else 1 end as 'Pondis Used', 1 as 'Volume', " & vbCr & vbLf & "FeedDensity AS 'Feed Density',round(cast(FeedDensity * revolution as float(25)),2)/*cast as float for correct rounding*/ AS 'Feed Multiplier'," & vbCr & vbLf & "feedType as 'Feed Type', feedName as 'Feed Name', batchID AS 'FishBatchCode'" & vbCr & vbLf & vbCr & vbLf & "FROM dbo.vwStorageMASTER" & vbCr & vbLf & vbCr & vbLf & "WHERE fkLocationID = 1 AND fkStorageIndicator <> 3  ORDER BY sequenceNumber ASC", conn)
        conn.Open()

        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        da.Fill(dataTable)
    End Using
End Using

'Output tab-delimited
Dim delim As String = vbTab
Dim sb = New StringBuilder()

sb.AppendLine("Trafalgar Master File" & vbCr & vbLf & vbCr & vbLf)
sb.AppendLine(String.Join(delim, "Number of Ponds: ", dataTable.Rows.Count.ToString() & vbCr & vbLf & vbCr & vbLf))

sb.AppendLine(String.Join(delim, dataTable.Columns.Cast(Of DataColumn)().[Select](Function(arg) arg.ColumnName)))
For Each dataRow As DataRow In dataTable.Rows
    sb.AppendLine(String.Join(delim, dataRow.ItemArray.[Select](Function(arg) arg.ToString())))
Next

'Prompt user to download tab-delimited file
Dim FileName As String = "test.xls"
Dim response As System.Web.HttpResponse = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response
response.ClearContent()
response.Clear()
response.ContentType = "text/plain"
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & FileName & ";")
response.Write(sb.ToString())
response.Flush()
response.[End]()
End Sub
```

Comment: Good thing you didn't use an server controls. That would have been rough.

Comment: Also: the .Net version could have been so much faster if you used a DataReader instead of a DataTable and wrote the output directly to the response stream vs building a huge string. As it is, you're basically holder (at least) 3 copies of your entire page in memory to full the http request.

Comment: i'll have a stab at it as well, I haven't played with vbscript since asp.net / vb.net was released. I know the syntax looks similar but vbs to vb6 or vice versa, easy. vb.net to vbscript will be a little more difficult.

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback and for having a go at converting if you did or are doing. Please comment why the minus vote =(

Comment: 99 View as of today but just 1 downvote, I have voted to close if otherwise wish to do likewise, this question is unlikely to help other in the future as too localised I feel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was how I rewrote it for my application. In the end I basically started again but it's result is pretty much the same;

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="1252"%>
<%Response.Buffer = True%>
<!--#include file="Conn/conn.asp" -->
<% 
Call DownloadFile()

Private Sub DownloadFile()
Dim Comm
Dim rst
Dim delim
delim = vbTab
response.Clear

set rst = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rst.ActiveConnection = MM_Conn_STRING
rst.Open "Select COUNT(*) from vwTrafalgarMasterFile"

'Write titles
Response.Write("Trafalgar Master File" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf)
Response.Write("Number of Ponds: " & rst.Fields(0).Value & vbcrlf & vbcrlf)

If rst.State = 1 Then rst.Close 'Used 1 instead of AdStateOpen as this seemed to cause an error
rst.Open "Select * from vwTrafalgarMasterFile"

'Write headers
If Not rst.EOF Then
    For Each fld In rst.Fields
        Response.Write(fld.Name & delim)
   Next
   Response.Write vbcrlf
Else
    Response.Write("There was a problem retrieving data or no data could be retrieved")
    Response.End
    Exit sub
End if

'Write rows
With rst
.MoveFirst
Do Until .EOF
    For Each fld In rst.Fields
        Response.Write(fld.Value & delim)
    Next
    Response.Write vbcrlf
        .Movenext
    Loop
End With

Dim FileName
FileName = "TrafalgarMasterFile.xls"
response.ContentType = "text/plain"
response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName + ";"
response.Flush
response.End

'Clean up
adoCMD.Close
Set Comm = Nothing
Set rst = Nothing
Set fld = Nothing
End Sub
%>
```

Answer (score 2):

While VB.Net and VBScript share a similar syntax, the objects that they use are entirely different animals. Vbscript has no knowledge of System.Web, System.Data, StringBuilder, etc. Instead, you might want to look into the VB6 syntax and the late bound CreateObject syntax to create AdoDb objects.